# Changing class object with function c++

Tags: c++, function, class, object

How do I change a class object such as "per.name" using a function? Is prototyping necessary? Function call? Is this passed by value or reference?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 


class Person {
    public:

    char* name; 
    int age;
    double weight;
    double height; 

    };

int main()
{ 
 Person per;
 per.name = "John"; //change per.name
 cout << per.name << endl;
 }
```

I want to change the name John. Is this made as a copy?

Comment: 1. `per.name = "John"; ` uses an old conversion that is no longer supported in c++. You can't assign a string literal to a non-const `char*`. 2. Assigning a new address to `name` would not copy the content of the string it now points to.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux What do you mean by "old conversion" in this case? Is that to do with `const char*` to `char*`?

Comment: @tadman `char *s = "Hallo";` used to be allowed, even though `"Hallo"` is `const` and `*s = 'W';` is UB. At some point C++ got rid of that and required the correct type `const char *s = "Hallo";` which makes `*s = 'W';` not compile.

Comment: @tadman It used to be legal to assign a `const char[]`'s address to a `char*`. This was deprecated in c++03 and removed in c++11.

Comment: @nwp Yeah, that makes sense. For some reason I was thinking of some other kind of conversion probably from spending too much time with Rust and Swift.

Answer (score 1):

`char* name;` allows you to store a non-`const` pointer to some character, or NUL-terminated variable-length text.  Because it's non-`const`, the C++ compiler won't let you point it at text that you're not allowed to modify, such as a string literal (your "John").

You would be better off adding...

```
#include <string>
```

...atop your file and changing the definition of the `name` member variable to:

```
std::string name;
```

That will then store a copy of any text you assign into the field in the `Person` object instance.

(Some very old C++ compilers did allow non-`const` character pointers to be pointed at string literals for compatibility with early C Standards, and current compilers will sometimes still support that if explicitly requested using command line arguments, with any attempt to "write through" the pointer to modify the text typically resulting in a program crash at runtime.  If you're using a textbook or reference material that suggested pointing a `char*` at a string literal, get a better, modern reference.)